# How to create an image.dd file to be used in virtualbox?

Tags: ubuntu, backup, virtualbox, virtualization, dd

I want to backup my Windows machine before I put Ubuntu on the hard drive instead.

Following the [instructions on the VirtualBox website](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Migrate_Windows) it says to create an `image.dd` file using `dd`.

I booted up from the Ubuntu live CD, connected the external hard drive and then tried to use `dd` to create the image with the following command:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb1/image.dd
```

However I get the following message:

```
 a dev/sdb1/image.dd: not a directory error
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/dev/sdb1 isn't a directory, so you can't create a file in there.

You need to have a filesystem on /dev/sdb1 (I assume the drive exists and is already partitioned?) that can be mounted.

Then you need to mount that filesystem:

```
# mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

should work.

Then you need to use

```
# dd if=/dev/sda of=/mnt/image.dd
```

Once it's finished, unmount the disk:

```
# umount /mnt
```

and you should be good to go.